# Bootstrap X-editable Table popup not correctly positioned when data-editable-type = "number"

Tags: x-editable, bootstrap-table

I have this fiddle and you can see that when you input any value for price field , It's popup tip is not positioned on the text because its data type is **number** as when you input values for Names.
https://jsfiddle.net/6da007fm/21/

**HTML**

```
<table data-toggle="table"
  data-editable-emptytext="This field is empty"
  data-id-field="id"
  data-url="/gh/get/response.json/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/docs/data/data2/">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="name" data-editable="true" >Name</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-editable="true" data-editable-emptytext="For free." data-editable-type="number" data-editable-placeholder="Enter a Number">Price</th>
```

JS

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
```

Is it a normal behavior or there is any workaround to this. I am using this in my project web page and it has 5 columns in one row and is not looking very neat because of this.

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to override popovers core css

```
 .popover{

  left:190px!important

}
```

here is your updated fiddle [Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/girish28892/6da007fm/22/)

Comment: It worked for the price field but disturbed the Name field

Comment: wait i'm out, ill look into it in a while